# Java group and summarize string list

Tags: java

I am writing a command program where I have a list of strings with the format as:

```
AAA 100
BBB 200
CCC 300
AAA 50
```

And the desired the output is to group the first column and summarize the second.

```
AAA 150
BBB 200
CCC 300
```

I use the code below and it works, but just wondering should it be a more elegant way of doing this?

```
public static Map<String, Integer> summarizeData(List<String> lines) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] temp;
    for (String line : lines) {
        temp = line.split("\\s+");
        if (map.containsKey(temp[0])) {
            int value = Integer.valueOf(temp[1])
                    + (Integer) map.get(temp[0]);
            map.put(temp[0], value);
        } else {
            map.put(temp[0], Integer.valueOf(temp[1]));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Many thanks guys.

Comment: This seems fine, except I don't get why you don't make it a `Map<String, Integer>`...

Comment: I could not resist my self from commenting.... In a very simple terms your requirement is analogous to a reduce phase of a map/reduce job . You have the keys now you are collating the values of similar keys.

BTW your solution is just fine. It might help if you are aware of the size of your input and setup the size of the hashmap accordingly.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap(int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work OK, but I would refactor it to simply:

```
public static Map<String, Object> summarizeData(List<String> lines) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] temp = line.split("\\s+");
        Integer total = map.get(temp[0]);
        total = total == null ? 0 : total;
        map.put(temp[0], total + Integer.valueOf(temp[1]));
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution won't necessarily sort the row names lexicographically. [Try](http://ideone.com/EHg46) my solution below.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> compile(final List<String> input) {
  final Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
  final Pattern space = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
  for (final String line : input) {
    final String[] parts = space.split(line, 0);
    final String name = parts[0];
    final int addendum = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
    final Integer old = map.get(name);
    map.put(name, old == null ? addendum : old + addendum);
  }
  return map;
}
```

... produces:

> ```
> AAA 150
> BBB 200
> CCC 300
> ```

Comment: Thanks Veer. It looks good except I guess you meant: map.put(name, old == null ? addendum : old + addendum);